# Fire Not Showing In Rendered view or LookDev but in other views Eevee

Tags: eevee-render-engine, fire

I've been losing my mind about this. Looked all over the place tried what others have. Nothing works.

I've designed a throne room and the braziers I have next to the throne must have fire. I add the smoke physics and what not. Everything looks good. Until I decide to look at it in Rendered View. Nothing was there. My fire was gone. Did the attribute thing by changing the flame attribute from "Flame" to "flame" restarted Blender. Nothing worked. Please help me out before I put a fist through my laptop.

Answer (score 0):

Can you post a screenshot of your fire material nodes? And do you have Volumetrics enabled for Cycles and EEVEE?

Answer (score 0):

Did you ramped up the multiply on the attribute node, like this:

[image]

(this is on the domain material)

Comment: There's no need for an _Add Shader_ if you don't have a very special reason to do it like that. You could simply plug the _Math Node_ multiplying the "flame" attribute into the _Emission Strength_ of the _Principled Volume Node_, and set the color under _Emission Color_. And instead of using an _Attribute Node_ (with the risk of misspelling "flame") you could use the _Flame_ socket of the _Volume Info Node_.

Answer (score 0):

Try increasing the blackbody setting  in  the principal volume.

Comment: Elaborate, if you could.

Answer (score -1):

this is old but I think I discovered your issue.  I had the same thing.  Your emission strength needs to be raised above 0.  Similar to the one above, if it's 0 you won't see anything in any view but solid.